# Determinant Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I know the following property of the Determinant:

$Det(A\cdot B)=Det(A)\cdot Det(B)$

When Trying to prove $Det(Adj(A))=Det(A)^{n-1}$ I came across the following dilemma:

$A\cdot Adj(A)=Det(A)\cdot I$  (multipling both sides in Det)

$Det(A)\cdot Det(Adj(A))=Det(Det(A)\cdot I)$

Does $Det(Det(A)\cdot I)=Det(Det(A))\cdot Det(I)$?

Maybe  the problem is that $Det(Det(A)\cdot I)$ can not be written as $Det(Det(A))\cdot Det(I)$ as the $Det(A)$ is scalar?

Comment: Exactly. $\det A$ is a scalar, so $\det ((\det A)I) \neq \det (\det A) \cdot \det I$.

Answer (score 3):

Call $a= \det A$. Then $aI$ is a diagonal matrix, so its determinant is the product of its diagonal entries. So
$$\det( (\det A)I) = \det(aI) = a^n = (\det A)^n$$

Comment: I think that I found the problem edited the question